# Netsuite: Auto approve Sales Orders through SuiteScripting

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

My organization is trying a new process, which includes importing sales orders from one of our shopping carts into Netsuite. When importing sales orders, I only have two options to choose the order status: "pending approval" and "pending fulfillment". If there was a way to approve sales orders in masse through SuiteScript, how would I be able to do so? I'm relatively new to SutieScripting, so I'm unsure what would be the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the 2 options that can be implemented for approving the sales orders

1. If you want to instantly (real time) approve the sales orders as soon as they are imported into NetSuite, the the best way would be to use a workflow for approval.
2. You can also consider using a scheduled or map reduce script (batch jobs) which can approve all the orders lying in a queue. A saved search can be used to pick all the sales order which are newly imported and pass the saved search data to your script.

In your case, you can import the sales order with a "pending approval" status in NetSuite and then build a workflow to set the status as "Approved"

Answer (score 0):

The sales order status indicates the stage in the fulfillment process. The sales order status can be either "Pending Approval" or "Pending Fulfillment".  So in a sense "Pending Fulfillment" could be the same as "Approved". I think it's better to say "when Status is not Pending Approval", since "Status" is a required field and other Statuses technically exist (i.e. Billed, Cancelled, Closed, Partial fulfilled, etc.).